# gmail SMTP server settings

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

Cant get this email to send and have no idea why. I tried switching ports to 587 and TLS.

```
<?php
// SMTP Server Settings
$config['smtp_host']            = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';       // eg.: smtp.mandrillapp.com
$config['smtp_port']            = 465;                          // eg.: 587
$config['smtp_user']            = 'myemail@gmail.com';          // you@gmail.com
$config['smtp_pass']            = 'myPassword';                 // password
$config['smtp_ssl']         = false;                        // should remain false

// Who receive all emails?
$config['send_to']              = 'myemail@gmail.com';          // destination of all emails sent through contact form

// Email Subject
$config['subject']              = 'Contact Form';               // subject of emails you receive
?>
```

Comment: have you enabled 'less secure apps' within your Gmail account?

Comment: Yes, I get an SMTP Error: Could not Authenticate